# r - download shinyapps code from my application

Tags: r, shinyapps

I'm trying to download my shiny app code on another pc from the shinyapps.io. I followed this example: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204536588-Downloading-your-application-from-shinyapps-io , unfortunately the downloaded file (bundle) is without an extension. Is there a way to extract this into something that can be opened in Rstudio ?

Comment: The file extension is convenient but unreliable, and the absence of it, while annoying, is not a huge problem. What have you tried? I'd think it could be a tar-gz file, in which case a (not R) command could be `tar tvzf mybundlefile` to view the contents; if that succeeds, then `tar xzf mybundlefile` will extract all contents into the current directory. (I often do this op in a new empty directory to preclude the likelihood of overwriting existing files.)

Comment: do you use cmd to execute ths command ?

Comment: I just work within a bash shell, but this can be done in many ways including `system`, `system2`, `processx::run`, or even (not-yet-tested) R's `untar()` function.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me for the exact same problem statement. I am using a windows 11 machine

step 1  : follow the instructions as given in [downloading your application from shiny](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204536588-Downloading-your-application-from-shinyapps-io)

step 2 : Assumption : your file was downloaded in your downloads tab then its a good practice to move it to a location which makes more sense. this step is redundant but I did it anyway

step 3 : opened cmd and changed directory to the new location in step 2

step 4 : used in the cmd the below code

```css
tar -xvzf myfilename.tar
```

end of steps : all the files from shiny that were used for the publishing is now available in the directory

Answer (score 0):

thanks to r2evans comment, i renamed the extracted file, and added ".tar". This helped me extract the contents.