# Retrieving the raw code an application hosted in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

Is there a way to get access to the raw code of an application hosted on Shinyapps.io. I hosted my shiny application on shiny apps and made multiple changes in my code in my system. I need the older version of my app which has been hosted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about downloading it from the dashboard?

[image: screenshot from shinyapps.io]

Please, note that you'll receive an extensionless file in the archive. Just add `.tar` to it, and you'll be able to open the file as an archive, as it was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65468577/3785618).